# How do I change the x-axis values in a Kaplan-Meier survival curve?

Tags: r

Please look at my R code and assist me on how to edit the x-axis labels. My attempts to change the x-axis labels change the plot completely. Thanks in advance.

```
attach(Pigments)
summary(Pigments)


library(survival)
library(survminer)

km.model <- survfit(Surv(Time.hours, Status)~1, data = Pigments)
plot(km.model,conf.int = T, xlab = "Time in minutes", ylab = "Cum Survival", main= "Cumulative Survival vs Time")
fit=survfit(Surv(Time.hours,Status) ~ Treatment )
survdiff(Surv(Time.hours,Status) ~ Treatment)
res <- pairwise_survdiff(Surv(Time.hours, Status) ~ Treatment,
                         data = Pigments)
res
plot(fit, conf.int = F)
model1<- survfit(Surv(Time.hours, Status) ~ rep(30,20), data =Pigments[1:20,], type= "kaplan-meier")
model2<- survfit(Surv(Time.hours, Status) ~ rep(40,21), data = Pigments[21:41,], type= "kaplan-meier")
model3<- survfit(Surv(Time.hours, Status) ~ rep(50,30), data = Pigments[42:71,], type= "kaplan-meier")
plot(model1, xlab = "Time in hours", ylab = "Cum Survival",conf.int = F)
lines(model1, xlab = "Time in hours", ylab = "cum survival", conf.int = F, col = 5)
lines(model2, xlab = "Time in hours", ylab = "Cum Survival",conf.int = F, col = 2)
lines(model3, xlab = "Time in hours", ylab = "Cum Survival",conf.int = F, col = 3,xlim = c(0,4)) 
legend("topright", cex = 0.65,bty ="n",lty =1, col =1:4)
       legend = c("Trained","Naive","Fed")
plot(1:300,
     xaxt = "n",
     xlab = "My X-Axis")
axis(1,
     at = c(10,50,100,150,200,250),
     labels = c(10,50,100,150,200,250))
```

Comment: Don't use a second `plot` command. If you want to use `axis()`, set `axes = FALSE` in your original `plot()` call, and use `axis()` subsequently to add them to the plot.

Comment: Hi, can we get a sample of the data?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Micro%20cage%20Refined%20data%2002-09-2020.csv

Comment: Gregor Thomas and Francesco Grossetti. Please find a hyperlink to a sample of my file in the prior message. Thanks in advance.